# Ramda JS partition array into multiple sub-arrays based on indices

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I would like to take an array and split it into a dictionary of sub-arrays based on another array of indices:

```
const arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
const indices = [0, 0, 1, 0, 3];
    
// Would like to do something like this:
R.split(indices, array) // { "0": ["A", "B", "D"], "1": ["C"], "3": ["E"] }
```

Is there an elegant way to do this in Ramda?

Answer (score 2):

Use `R.zip` combine the arrays to an array of values/indices pairs. Group by the indices, and then take only the values from the pairs:

```js
const { pipe, zip, groupBy, last, map, head } = R

const fn = pipe(
  zip, // combine the arrays to an array of value/indice pairs
  groupBy(last), // group by the indices
  map(map(head)) // take only the values from the pairs
)

const arr = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
const indices = [0, 0, 1, 0, 3]

const result = fn(arr, indices)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```